# Null pointer exception in FlashImpl.java in IBM JSF

Tags: jsf, myfaces, ibm-jsf

I am getting  a null pointer exception sometimes in my web application, which runs in RAD 8.5 and WAS 8.5 .

The exception is :

```
An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [Faces Servlet] in application [Gedit]. Exception created :
[java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.flash. FlashImpl.isKeepMessages(FlashImpl.java:367)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.flash. FlashImpl._saveMess`
```

I am not using `myfaces`, but the `ibm faces`. So , i am not understanding what may be the cause of this error . Can some one kindly help me out here ?

Comment: @BalusC : Any ideas ?? Hope you don't mind me tagging you here...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem recently. We were using WAS with LDAP using the form based authentication feature of WAS. we faced this issue when application security was disabled in the Admin console. Enable application security(Admin console -> security -> global security -> check enable application security and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem when a JSF 2.0 (base IBM Websphere 8.5.5 implementation) was deployed to a running server that had other applications on it.  After restarting the server, everything was fine.